# how to compare two linear lists in pascal

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, linked-list, structure, pascal

The task is to create new list which contains 2 linear lists, and if elements of first list equal to elements of second list then we must delete the same element from new list

```
 procedure CreateList(var t1,L1,t2,L2:plist);
 var 
 tmp1, tmp2:plist;
 begin
  t1 := L1;
  t2 := L2;
  while t1 <> nil do
  begin

  write(t1^.Data, ' ');
  t1 := t1^.Next;


  while t2 <> nil do
  begin
  write(t2^.data, '  ');
  tmp2:=t2;
  t2 := t2^.Next;

   if(t2 = tmp1^.next) then // here is the problem how to compare 2 elements
   begin
   tmp1 := t1; 
   t1 := t1^.Next;
   Dispose(tmp1); 
   end;
end; 
end;
Writeln;
readkey;
end;
```

Comment: 1. Are the two lists supposed to be sorted? 2. From your code as posted here, you seem to be comparing references, not the corresponding `Data` fields like I thought at first. Is that how you intended it to be? Or is that what you are actually having the problem with (i.e. *how to compare values*)?

Comment: 3. Also why are all your parameters being passed by reference? And why are there 4 of them? You said you wanted to create a new list (one list) from two lists, but your procedure has 4 parameters. What are they?

Comment: t1,L1 my first list ; t2, L2 second,, which are would be given and yes I have to compare values but how to do I do not know because always appear error.

Comment: well if I compare as t1^.data <> t2^.data i get an error from compilator

Comment: Right, that much is clear. There are other things that are unclear about your question and about your code snippet at the moment, but rather than wear you out with my questions, please let me simply recap what you've got and what you are trying to achieve as I understand it, and if I've missed something, kindly correct me. So, you've got 2 linked lists. Some values are present in both lists, and some only in one or the other. You want to create a new list (new structure) and populate it with values that are only present in one or the other of the two existing lists. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to change type of you list for something like:

```
type
  TData = integer;

  PList = ^TList;
  TList = record
    data : TData;
    next : PList;
    copy : boolean;
  end;
```

After you will use value .copy for checking copys. Here is simple code you need.
I tried to make all code as simple as possible.

```
procedure deleteCopys(var list:PList);
// make all TList.copy := false (after we will use it)
var
  curList : PList;
begin
  curList := list;
  while (curList<>nil) do
  begin
    curList^.copy := false;
    curList := curList^.next;
  End;
End;

procedure createList(var list1, list2, list3:PList);
// we belive that: (list3 is empty) and (there is no copys in list1)
//                 and (there is no copys in list2)
var
  curList1, curList2 : PList;
begin
  deleteCopys(list1);
  deleteCopys(list2);
  deleteCopys(list3);

  // make TList.copy := true for equal elements 
  // from curList1 and curList2
  curList1 := list1;
  while (curList1 <> nil) do
  begin
    curList2 := list2;
    while (curList2 <> nil) do
    begin
      if (curList1^.data = curList2^.data) then
      begin
        curList1^.copy := true;
        curList2^.copy := true;
        break;
      End;
      curList2 := curList2^.next;
    End;
    curList1 := curList1^.next;
  End;

  // now we can put all elements from list1 and list2 
  // with state TLilt.copy=false
  // and each of them will be different
  // (Let's do it :)
  curList1 := list1;
  while (curList1 <> nil) do
  begin
    if (curList1^.copy = false) then
    begin
      //some procedure for new element
      putNewElement(list3, curList1^.data);
    End;
  End;

  curList2 := list2;
  while (curList2 <> nil) do
  begin
    if (curList2^.copy = false) then
    begin
      //some procedure for new element
      putNewElement(list3, curList2^.data);
    End;
  End;

end;
```

I hope it will help you!